# Wildcards in dlookup

Tags: vba, wildcard, lookup

I am trying to search the a table named "PeopleRecords" for a desk location given only the persons first name. Every time I attempt using a wild card I return "nope". How should I correctly use the wildcard?

```
param = Nz(DLookup("DeskLocation", "PeopleRecords", "[FullName] = '" & FirstName & "'"), "nope")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
param = Nz(DLookup("DeskLocation", "PeopleRecords", "[FullName] LIKE '" & FirstName & "*'"), "nope")
```

Just edit the criteria to `LIKE` and add a wildcard (i.e. `*` for zero to x characters) after the name.

Comment: It didn't work, but replacing the % with a * did. Thank you very much kind sir.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Using wildcards in Access is not as trivial as it seems ;) Editing the answer.

Comment: Additionally, as an fyi to anyone who reads this in the future, if you test this line in the VBA debugger, don't forget to remove the extra quotes.